# Node.js arguments when using forever

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm currently using forever to run my node.js application in our development environment. What I am currently struggling with is how to pass node.js arguments when using "forever start"

Here is an example where I need to pass a number and a date to node. It's not working so any help would be appreciated.

```
forever -c 'node 8010 "2014-11-11 12:00:00"' start app.js
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the documentation, the script arguments come after the call.
https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

usage: forever [action] [options] SCRIPT [script-options]

```
forever start app.js 8010 "2014-11-11 12:00:00"
```

The usage of nconf https://github.com/flatiron/nconf in your project is highly recommended to grab those  params.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. (Maybe I should have read the documentation properly)

Comment: Hey @Will Shaver apart from params if I want to pass some node specific parameters like "--prof" is it possible?

Comment: @Vipresh I think you are looking for this one:
 forever start -c "node --harmony_proxies" server.js

Comment: If you want to have args before the script, use the `--command` option